# WiFi info popup broken and not showing all info on Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

[image: wifi info popup broken]

So my popup window for WiFi info is broken on Nexus using android 5.0.1. That's not that bad, but i was also wondering why is it not showing other important WiFi information's, such as IP address? I need my IP often and its hard for me to go to terminal and type ip addr show each time i need it. Is that info removed or is my popup somehow broken?

Comment: Your popup layout is definitely broken, but I also don't find IP address on Nexus 4 running 5.0.1 Lollipop. Regarding the layout, you might as well post this on [AOSP issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry) if it bothers you.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than clicking on the network name, click the three little dots on the top right corner of the screen, then select Advanced. The IP is listed at the bottom of the screen.